# iterate over a list of columns using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using a for loop to iterate over columns. I am selecting the columns using the slicing. This is perfectly working. But when I provide a list of columns(cols) to iterate over it fails with the error

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I have tried it with a list of integers too but failed. How to iterate over selected columns as in this case

code :

```
for column in df1.columns[2:14]:

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for column in df1.columns[cols]:
```

Comment: Try: `for column in df1[cols]:`

Answer (score 0):

First select columns by `list` and then get columns:

```
for column in df1[cols].columns:
    print (column)
```

Another solution is also possible, but worse readable in my opinion:

```
for column in df1[cols]:
    print (column)
```

Comment: Thank you, but finally  "for column in columns" worked. Here the "columns" is a list of columns